# Error al ejecutar JAR: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .jar

Tags: java, netbeans, maven

alguien me podría ayudar con el siguiente error al ejecutar el .jar de mi proyecto de Maven ya compilado:

**Error: Could not find or load main class ISSSTEregs-1.0.jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ISSSTEregs-1.0.jar**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya cambié el *mainClass* dentro de **pom.xml** pero me sigue mostrando el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Ernesto, no deberías usar **`java -jar "xx.jar"`** ?.

Comment: por que el titulo dice abrir y el contenido dice ejecutar? deberias de corregir eso

Comment: con java -jar igual me sigue dando el error, pero me muestra específicasmente cual es el error

Comment: ya lo correguí, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Es sencillo, ubícate en el root de tu proyecto y ejecuta `java -jar "nombredetujar.jar"`  y listo. Recuerda antes hacer el clean e install.

Comment: Ya logre que cambiara de error, ahora me muestra el siguiente:
**no main manifest attribute, in ISSSTEregs-1.0.jar**

Comment: Debes indicar el manifiest y agregarle la clase Main, algo más o menos asi: co.com.company.etc.MainClass pero en el manifiest.

Comment: Seria bueno que le pusieras segun la documentacion que significa el `-jar` y por qué es la razon de su error